# How to resolve emit was called after an event handler completed normally bloc error?

Tags: flutter, dart, state, bloc

I am using flutter bloc to make download progress percentage displayed but I keep getting this problem. I figured the problem arises in the `onDone` method but I couldn't figure out how to fix it.

**ERROR :**

*Exception has occurred.
_AssertionError ('package:bloc/src/bloc.dart': Failed assertion: line 137 pos 7: '!_isCompleted':
emit was called after an event handler completed normally.
This is usually due to an unawaited future in an event handler.
Please make sure to await all asynchronous operations with event handlers
and use emit.isDone after asynchronous operations before calling emit() to
ensure the event handler has not completed.*

**BAD**

```
 on<Event>((event, emit) {
    future.whenComplete(() => emit(...));
  });
```

**GOOD**

```
  on<Event>((event, emit) async {
    await future.whenComplete(() => emit(...));
  });
)
```

**CODE :**

```
import 'package:bloc/bloc.dart';
import 'package:download_progress_with_bloc/downlaod_file.dart';
import 'package:download_progress_with_bloc/download_event.dart';
import 'package:download_progress_with_bloc/download_state.dart';
import 'package:download_progress_with_bloc/permission_handler.dart';
import 'package:download_progress_with_bloc/store_book_repo.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

class DownloadBloc extends Bloc<DownloadEvent, DownloadState> {
  DownloadBloc({required this.storeBookRepo}) : super(DownloadInitial()) {
    on<DownloadStarted>(onStarted);
    on<DownloadProgressed>(onProgressed);
  }
  final StoreBookRepo storeBookRepo;

  http.StreamedResponse? response;
  // StreamController? _controller;
  int received = 0;
  List<int> bytes = [];
  int totalSize = 0;

  @override
  Future<void> close() {
    return super.close();
  }

  Future<void> onStarted(
      DownloadStarted event, Emitter<DownloadState> emit) async {
    try {
      await PermissionHandler.requestStoragePermission();
      response = await downloadFile();
      totalSize = response!.contentLength ?? 0;
      emit(DownloadInProgress(progress: received, totalSize: totalSize));
      response?.stream.asBroadcastStream().listen((value) async {
        received += value.length;
        bytes.addAll(value);
        add(DownloadProgressed(progress: received));
        print('received value is $received');
      }).onDone(
        () async {
          await storeBookRepo
              .storePdf(
                bytes.toString(),
                bookTitle: 'bookTitle',
              )
              .then((value) => emit(DownloadCompleted()));
          // emit(DownloadCompleted());
        },
      );
    } catch (e) {
      emit(DownlaodFailed(errorMessage: '$e'));
    }
  }

  void onProgressed(DownloadProgressed event, Emitter<DownloadState> emit) {
    emit(DownloadInProgress(progress: event.progress, totalSize: totalSize));
  }


}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

What if rewrite `listen` to `await for` like this?

```dart
Future<void> onStarted(
  DownloadStarted event,
  Emitter<DownloadState> emit,
) async {
  try {
    await PermissionHandler.requestStoragePermission();
    response = await downloadFile();
    totalSize = response!.contentLength ?? 0;

    emit(DownloadInProgress(
      progress: received,
      totalSize: totalSize,
    ));

    await for (final value in response?.stream) {
      received += value.length;
      bytes.addAll(value);

      add(DownloadProgressed(progress: received));
      print('received value is $received');
    }

    await storeBookRepo.storePdf(
      bytes.toString(),
      bookTitle: 'bookTitle',
    );

    emit(DownloadCompleted());
  } catch (e) {
    emit(DownlaodFailed(errorMessage: '$e'));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

use `async` before `on` bloc and `await` for Future operations

```
on<NumberTriviaEvent>((event, emit) async {
   await Future func(){
     //some time consuming operation like fetch data
   }
   emit(YourState())  
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I have this error too

In my case, when using Flutter_Bloc with Freezed If you used the event.when() etc. you must await the event.when like this and add async in each event when you use await

```
    Future<void> _onAddSection(
    SectionEvent event,
    Emitter<SectionState> emit,
  ) async {
    await event.whenOrNull(
      addSection: (sectionViewModel, chapterName) async {
        emit(const SectionState.loading());
        final section =
            _sectionMapper.convert<SectionViewModel, Section>(sectionViewModel);
        final result =
            await _sectionRepository.addSection(section, chapterName);
        result.fold(
          (failure) => emit(SectionState.failure(message: failure.message)),
          (data) => emit(SectionState.success(message: data)),
        );
      },
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

you should use async and await , its clear.
but why?
before complete run of each on() method, you can use emiteer. after that bloc will dispose or cancel that emitter.